# python split string that by space and new line character

Tags: python, split

I have this code:

```
f1=open('test.txt','r')
d={}
line = f1.read().replace('\n',' ')
line2= line.split("\n")
```

`line = "This is line1\nthis isline2\nthis is line3"`

My question is: can I do a split with multiple delimiters rather than replace
first, then do a split?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split).

Splitting on `\n` and `\t`:

```
In [23]: line = "This is line1\nthis isline2\tthis is line3"

In [24]: re.split(r'[\n\t]', line)
Out[24]: ['This is line1', 'this isline2', 'this is line3']
```